# Spinner Is Not Correctly Redrawn

Tags: java, swt

I have a curious case where a SWT spinner refuses to be redrawn.

I've added a working example below. While the paint listener is called on each button click, there is no change in what is displayed until you move the mouse over the spinner control. (Additionally, if the mouse hovers over the little arrow, the text "<overlay>" is drawn there, too.)

```
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

Spinner spinner = new Spinner(shell, SWT.BORDER);
spinner.addListener(SWT.Paint, e -> {
    if ("overlay".equals(spinner.getData("test")) && !spinner.isFocusControl()) {
    e.gc.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GRAY));
    e.gc.drawText("<overlay>", 0, 0, false);
    }
});

Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
button.setText("Overlay!");
button.addListener(SWT.Selection, e -> {
    spinner.setData("test", "overlay");
    spinner.redraw();
});

button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
button.setText("Remove");
button.addListener(SWT.Selection, e -> {
    spinner.setData("test", null);
    spinner.redraw();
});

shell.setSize(300, 80);
shell.open();

while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
    }
}
display.dispose();
```

If you insert a `Text` widget, everything works as expected. So what's wrong with the `Spinner`?

(I'm building against SWT 3.7)

Comment: Did you try to replace the redraw() command with spinner.layout()? Did you try shell.layout() and shell.redraw() after updating the spinner?

Comment: @milez Yes, I was frustrated enough to try any of these.

Comment: Then I'm clueless :)

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you really want to do. Trying to paint a Spinner is going to be very platform dependent - on my Mac the "<overlay>" text is drawn outside of the Spinner.

Comment: @greg-449 I'm using duplexing databinding and want to display the spinner in a way to make it clear to the user that the selected values are different. Since spinners don't allow empty values I'm stuck with painting stuff over the control. But yes, maybe a relevant info: I'm using Windows, so are all our customers.

Comment: I think the UI needs rethinking. Possibly something like a group of radio buttons with the Spinner only enabled when the appropriate button is selected. You could ask the people on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ what they think is a suitable UI.

Comment: @greg-449 How would radio buttons help? This is nothing the user can change, it's purely aesthetic to display the info that the spinner is now in a state where it's value is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @greg-449 comments, controls are not meant to be drawn on by `PaintListeners`. In most cases this will interfere with what the window system draws.

If you want to have an overlay you may want to try to position a `Canvas` on top of the client area of the `Spinner` and then draw thereon.

The overlay control would have to be excluded from the parent's layout, e.g. with `GridData#exclude` or by using a `FormLayout`.

Another obstacle to deal with are probably the mouse events that are sent to the overlay control but may need to be forwarded to the Spinner.

And of course `FocusListener`s on the Spinner that show and hide the overlay control when the Spinner loses or gains focus.

Comment: So why do Controls even have `PaintListener`s? With no warning whatsoever that they should not be used? Even [eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-graphics/SWT_graphics.html) seems to think painting on controls is okay... Also, since I'm working on a databinding framework, creating additional controls is out of the question.

Comment: You are right, it should probably at least be documented that `PaintListener`s cannot be used everywhere. You may want [file an enhancement request against SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/bugs.php) therefore. The examples work around this issue in that they only use controls which don't draw themseves within their client area (Sehll, Canvas).